# Joomla Media manager cannot open video files

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

In a module's configuration file, I set the parameter as

```
                <field
                name="file"
                type="media"
                default="video.mp4"
                directory="videos"
                label="MOD_PLAYER_FIELD_FILE_LABEL"
                description="MOD_PLAYER_FIELD_FILE_DESC"/>
```

Then I log in as the admin, open the module manager and that module. When I click on the select button beside the 'file' field, the media manager window loads but it can only see/select image files. How could make it be able to select video files?

Thanks!

Comment: have you included the video formats in alphabetical order under media manger settings? Path- administrator -> Content -> Media Manager -> options in joomla 2.5.3

Comment: Yes, I haved added some video formats e.g. mp4.      "bmp,csv,doc,flv,gif,ico,jpg,jpeg,mp4,odg,odp,ods,odt,pdf,png,ppt,swf,txt,xcf,xls,BMP,CSV,DOC,FLV,GIF,ICO,JPG,JPEG,MP4,ODG,ODP,ODS,ODT,PDF,PNG,PPT,SWF,TXT,XCF,XLS"

Comment: As I found so far, Joomla sets file type filter for the image view of media component which is to be opened by clicking on select button of the parameter type 'media'.

Answer (score 0):

By default this sadly doesn't work (at least in Joomla 2.5.*). In an older project we had to hack the `com_media` component for this to work. You need to apply the following change

```
diff --git a/administrator/components/com_media/models/list.php b/administrator/components/com_media/models/list.php
index b97a930..ebee3f4 100644
--- a/administrator/components/com_media/models/list.php
+++ b/administrator/components/com_media/models/list.php
@@ -156,7 +156,7 @@ class MediaModelList extends JModel
                        default:
                            $tmp->icon_32 = "media/mime-icon-32/".$ext.".png";
                            $tmp->icon_16 = "media/mime-icon-16/".$ext.".png";
-                           $docs[] = $tmp;
+                           $images[] = $tmp;
                            break;
                    }
                }
```

Video and audio files will now show up using the "media" type, albeit with a broken image icon (as they have none). This patch could obviously be improved further by adding the necessary image information manually.